# Could Batman survive this?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52

In the Court of Owls, Batman

> is stabbed in the back and the blade protruded through his stomach

I'm sure in the real world he couldn't have defeated the bad guy after that. But is it even possible that he survived ?

> [image]

Comment: People have survived being impaled by things.  It would just require that he is lucky enough that it missed all the really vital bits.

Comment: Batman is DCs biggest seller, so yes he will survive

Comment: While this may seem like its asking for an explanation of something from the real world, Batman has above human durability which borders on SF/F.

Comment: Do you have a picture? Was it his [*stomach* or *abdomen*](http://www.healthhype.com/wp-content/uploads/stomach_pain.jpg)?

Comment: People have survived being cut in half.  Phineas Gage survived having s metal pipe blown through his skull.  You can survive almost anything except losing your heart, brain, or both lungs.  Most people *don't* survive stuff like being impaled through the chest, but it is *possible*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. It boils down to two questions: did any vital organs/intestines get scratched/punctured, and how long did he have to wait before he had medical attention. The first answer will to a degree affect the second one of course.

But yea, it's dangerous and painful but ultimately survivable if there is no massive trauma and he seeks a surgeon immediately.

Edit: of course I say this not seeing the image of it being done to better judge the extent of damage.

Edit: the image now being posted, that looks less like Bat**man** and more like Bat**werewolf** so now that's a different game entirely that you can't really judge.

Comment: You can live without most of your intestines.

Comment: Full disclaimer: We are all competent doctors here on SFF, you can most definitely count on us for any medical advice.

Comment: @WadCheber not when they've been forcibly severed out in the open. (Not allowed to @ apparently)ibid I actually am a competent doctor, thank you.

Comment: @Broklynite - tell that the the guy who was chewed open by an elephant and had his intestines piled on top of his body in a wheelbarrow by a ranger...  and survived.  True story.

Comment: @WadCheber And did the ranger take him to a hospital to get treated?

Comment: I assume so.  I was more interested in the elephant chewing him up and stomping on him.

Comment: So...we go back to the second sentence in my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Batman has above peak human durability (without being supernaturally though), taking blows from Wonder Woman and Azazel and surviving.

[image: Wonder Woman beating up bats]

[image: Azazel beating up bats]

<sub>(both sourced from this [respect thread](https://np.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/3m63vw/respect_batman_bruce_wayne_pcn52/) on reddit by [/u/Ame-no-nobuko](https://www.reddit.com/user/Ame-no-nobuko). )</sub>

Further more every day people  have survived such punishment [as](http://www.oddee.com/item_98009.aspx) [well](http://med.news.am/eng/news/2358/5-x-ray-photos-you-have-to-see-to-believe.html)

Warning!  Some disturbing images in those two links.

So yes,  he can definitely survive the wounds he suffers in Court of owls.

Comment: As Batman is human, [by definition](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--l6Iur1KF--/kcsvluovgtqaizlvcpe8.jpg), none of his characteristics are "above human." Hopefully this will earn me the secret hidden "pedant" badge that I assume exists.

Comment: Perhaps "well above average human" would be better put.